# How to download file and correctly handle exceptions?

Tags: java

My method for downloading file. It's a bit simplified, I removed the third argument - DownloadListener, which I use to inform the caller about dowonload progress.

```
public static boolean downloadFile(String url, File file) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        is.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I guess that the exceptions are not handled correctly but if I put the close() calls into finally block, they would have to be surrounded by try-catch block which would look very messy. There must be some cleaner way how to correctly download file in Java. Another thing is, should I call `connection.disconnect()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not until Java 7's [ARM](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_arm_api).  You're right, that often you need nested `try-finally` blocks within a `finally` block, in order to definitively clean up multiple resources.  And that the correct way of doing it doesn't look very tidy if done in-line.

This is often a good candidate for extracting a static helper method (such as something like `IOUtils.closeConnection()`); the method can catch any exception, so as to avoid an exception stopping further resources from being closed.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that every resources that is utilized, must be closed (released) in the `finally` block. You don't want situations when you have open connection that isn't closed and trying to establish another connection and the the previous resource hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     InputStream is = null;
     try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = 
                   (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            is =  = connection.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }


            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            return false;
        }finally{
            myClose(is);
            myFlush(fos);
            myClose(fos);

   }     }

    public void myClose(Closable c){
      if(c == null)
         return;
      try{
         c.close();
      }catch(IOException ex)
        //perform necessary things
       }
    }
    public void myFlush(Flushable f){
      if(f == null)
        return;
      try{
         f.flush();
      }catch(IOException ex)
         //perform necessary things
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting 'is' or 'fos' to close() in catch makes it unreachable.

Comment: If you add is.close() and fos.close() to the catch() clause, it would make the 'is' and 'fos' variable unreachable. I compiled the codes with the unreachable statements in my netbeans and this is what it shows:"/home/../Main.java:111: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable is
location: class test.Main
                is.close();
/home/../Main.java:112: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable fos
location: class test.Main
                fos.close();
2 errors"